# Recording stereo with external mic on iOS AudioKit

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, audiokit

I'm trying to integrate AudioKit into our app for audio processing. The audio comes from mic input fed into the iOS device and we have had no problems with the integrated mics on the iPhone. However, we're trying to get stereo input and so we're using an external mic that plugs into the lighting port. The mic is the Shure MV88. The input we're getting is dual mono and not stereo. Is there a setting we need to toggle or change in the code to get stereo? I've tried setting channelCount to 2 but that doesn't make a difference.

EDIT: Some code of how we're using AudioKit to capture mic input:

```
AKSettings.useBluetooth = true
AKSettings.bluetoothOptions = [.allowBluetoothA2DP, .allowAirPlay]

// Configure AudioKit for low latency
AKSettings.bufferLength = .medium           
AKSettings.sampleRate = 16000               

AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
AKSettings.channelCount = 2
AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = false

mic = AKMicrophone()
AudioKit.output = mic

let format = [
     AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 32,
     AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: 0,
     AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
     AVFormatIDKey: 1819304813,
     AVSampleRateKey: 16000,
     AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: 1,
     AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: 1
     ]

// Install input tap
do {
     inputFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: inputPath, settings: format)
} catch {
     AKLog("Error with output file: \(error)")
}
mic.avAudioNode.installTap(onBus: 0,
     bufferSize: 4096,
     format: mic.avAudioNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0),
     block: { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, _) -> Void in
          do {
               try self.inputFile.write(from: buffer)
          } catch {
               print(NSString(string: "Write failed: \(error)"))
          }
})

do {
     try AudioKit.start()
} catch {
     AKLog("AudioKit did not start")
}
```

Comment: Have you experimented with Voice Memo app? It will record in stereo and help make sure that your external setup is correct. It may help to show your recording code here, and how you're determining that it's dual mono to eliminate any obvious errors. I would also try a simple setup with AVFoundation (AVAudioEngine and installTap) to take the 3rdparty framework out of the equation (I assume you mean audiokit.io here).

Comment: I posted some code of how we're using AudioKit to my original post. I've also tried setting up a sample app as @RobNapier suggested that records mic input using AVAudioEngine and installTap to write to a .caf file and can confirm it records flawlessly in stereo. So it seems it is a problem with AudioKit or at least how I am using AudioKit.

Comment: @ManyHatsNeth Did you fix this issue?